# Change Item Height of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set combobox item height? My combobox.size=new size(320,40) and I had set combobox.itemheight=18 but it didn't work. I want my itemheight or text height to be 18, and fixed size for the combobox which is 320x40. I used also drawmode property but nothing is happening.

Comment: Change `DrawMode` to *OwnerDrawFixed* and then set `ItemHeight` to the value you want; however, you have to draw the items manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to prevent combobox resizing to its default height, you can declare it being manually drawing:

```
myComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed; // or DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
myComboBox.Height = 18; // <- what ever you want
```

Then you have to implement `DrawItem` event:

```
private void myComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
  ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;

  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, box))
    return;

  e.DrawBackground();

  if (e.Index >= 0) {
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    using (Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                          ? new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight)
                          : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor)) {
      using (Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)) { 
        g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);

        g.DrawString(box.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
                     e.Font,
                     textBrush, 
                     e.Bounds, 
                     StringFormat.GenericDefault);
      }
    }
  }

  e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

**Edit**: to have the combobox *stretched*, but *not* its dropdown list

```
   myComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable; 
   myComboBox.Height = 18; // Combobox itself is 18 pixels in height

   ...

   private void myComboBox_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
     e.ItemHeight = 17; // while item is 17 pixels high only
   }
```

Comment: @XXX: since its `OwnerDraw` it's your task to get a appropriate font (or at least size); you've insisted on height which is more than recommended one, so the immediate effect is that spacing are large; the other possibility is `OwnerDrawVariable` mode and `MeasureItem` event; see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Try changing Font Size of your combo box

Comment: i tried ComboBox.ItemHeight = 18 but didnt work either

Comment: Change its font size instead of itemheight

Comment: ComboBox.Font = new Font("Tahoma",18, FontStyle.Bold); it changed the font height but the combobox height is also changing which is become shorter