# Setting ComboBox Items Height

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a touch application but the items of my ComboBox are very small.
Is there any way to increase its size?
I haven't found any way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746306/styling-wpf-combobox-items.

Comment: @DanielCorzo: I cannot see where that link gives any reference to resizing the items - can you point out where please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Item Height of ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332518/change-item-height-of-combobox)

Comment: @confusedandamused, it's for winforms.. /facepalm

Comment: You can style controls in WPF, basically by altering `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`. The problem with `ComboBox` is what you don't want to change template for selected item, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33421573/1997232) (in fact it looks complicated, but I can't find simpler where you just define own template selector and use it for ComboBox, poke me if you still have problems tomorrow).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will do it, just give it the height and/or width you want within these setters.

```
 <ComboBox Width="200"
           Height="50"
           ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ComboBox>
```